# Building a scrollbar in a frame using place method

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry for the jumbled mess of code I am getting a bit flustered with trying to solve this sidebar. I am attempting to build a sidebar in a frame using Tkinter and the sidebar appears and the entries are populated into the window although the scrollbar does not build and does not scroll down the frame. I am struggling at figuring out how to make it work and would really appreciate some assistance.

```
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 10

        if not self.first_search_run:
            self.main_frame_content.destroy()
            self.main_frame_content_scrollbar.destroy()
            self.main_frame_content_canvas.destroy()
            self.main_frame_content_handler.destroy()

        self.main_frame_content = Frame(main)
        self.main_frame_content.place(relx=256/1280, rely=72/720, relwidth=1024/1280, relheight=648/720)

        self.main_frame_content_canvas = Canvas(self.main_frame_content)
        self.main_frame_content_handler = Frame(self.main_frame_content_canvas)
        self.main_frame_content.configure(background=mal_white)

        self.main_frame_content_canvas.bind("<Configure>", scroll_handler)

        self.main_frame_content_scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.main_frame_content_canvas, orient="vertical", command=self.main_frame_content_canvas)
        self.main_frame_content_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = self.main_frame_content_scrollbar.set)

        self.main_frame_content_scrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")
        self.main_frame_content_canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.main_frame_content_canvas.configure(background=mal_white)

        self.main_frame_content_handler.configure(background=mal_white)

        self.main_frame_content_handler.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1, anchor=NW)


        if self.first_search_run:
            self.object_list = []
            self.entry_list = []
            self.image_list = []
            self.entry_builder = 0
            self.entry_builder_support = 0
            self.first_search_run = False
        else:
            for entry in self.entry_list:
                entry.destroy()

            self.object_list = []
            self.entry_list = []
            self.image_list = []
            self.entry_builder = 0
            self.entry_builder_support = 0

        for entry in self.search_response:

            try:
                image_load = urllib.request.urlopen(entry[11].text)
            except AttributeError:
                image_load = urllib.urlopen(entry[11].text)

            image_load = image_load.read()
            image_load = BytesIO(image_load)
            self.image = PIL.Image.open(image_load)
            self.image = self.image.resize((144, 203), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.entry_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

            self.main_content_entry = Canvas(self.main_frame_content_handler)
            self.main_content_entry.place(relx=self.x/1024, rely=self.y/648, relwidth=144/1024, relheight=203/648)
            self.main_content_entry_tooltip = Tooltip(self.main_content_entry, entry)

            self.object_list.append(entry)
            self.entry_list.append(self.main_content_entry)
            self.image_list.append(self.entry_image)

            self.x += 154
            self.entry_builder += 1
            self.entry_builder_support += 1

            if self.entry_builder_support == 6:
                self.y += 213
                self.x = 50
                self.entry_builder_support = 0

        self.entry_builder = 0

        for image in self.image_list:

            self.entry_list[self.entry_builder].create_image(72, 203/2, image = image)

            self.entry_builder += 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question is quite long and cannot be executed as is, so I am just giving a small example of how to scroll a frame by embedding it in a canvas.

In order for the scrollbar to scroll properly the frame, you need to update the `scrollregion` attribute of the canvas each time the size of the frame changes.

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_configure(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)

frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
# resize the canvas scrollregion each time the size of the frame changes
frame.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)
# display frame inside the canvas
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=frame)

scrolly = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
scrolly.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1, anchor='ne')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrolly.set)

# populate the frame
for i in range(20):
    tk.Label(frame, text='Label %i' % i).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Let me know if you have troubles adapting this example to your code.

Comment: I am trying to use your logic. It works fine when I use `pack()` method for packing widgets in the frame, but It does NOT show any widgets when packed them using `place()` command. I am wondering what I am missing here.

Comment: @SatishThorat `place` is not very practical to use as it does not adapt well to window resizing, adding other widgets ... What might be happening in your case is that your frame is too small to show the widgets you put in. Keep in mind that with `place` you need to manually resize the frame to accommodate all the widgets. So, in general, I would advise against using `place` except for very specific cases.